# Mongodb limit, index and sort order

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am struggling to understans Mongodb performance in relation to filter, sort and limit.

I have a collection with 32 million documents, size 5 GB.

I have this query:

```
db.report_meter_device_audit.find({
    "$and": [{ "receivedTime": { "$gt": new ISODate("2020-12-31T00:00:00Z") } },
    { "receivedTime": { "$lt": new ISODate("2021-05-31T00:00:00Z") } }]
}).sort({ meterid: 1 }).limit(100);
```

and built this index:

```
(meterid:1 , receivedTime:-1)
```

This query returns very fast, and explain.executionStats shows this:

```
    "winningPlan" : {
                "stage" : "LIMIT",
                "limitAmount" : 100,
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "FETCH",
                    "filter" : {
                        "$and" : [
                            {
                                "receivedTime" : {
                                    "$lt" : ISODate("2021-05-31T03:00:00.000+03:00")
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "receivedTime" : {
                                    "$gt" : ISODate("2020-12-31T02:00:00.000+02:00")
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                        "keyPattern" : {
                            "meterid" : 1,
                            "receivedTime" : -1
                        },
                        "indexName" : "meterid_time_idx",
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "multiKeyPaths" : {
                            "meterid" : [ ],
                            "receivedTime" : [ ]
                        },
                        "isUnique" : false,
                        "isSparse" : false,
                        "isPartial" : false,
                        "indexVersion" : 2,
                        "direction" : "forward",
                        "indexBounds" : {
                            "meterid" : [
                                "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                            ],
                            "receivedTime" : [
                                "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
.
.
"executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 100,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 3,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 100,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 100,
        "executionStages" : {
            "stage" : "LIMIT",
            "nReturned" : 100,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
            "works" : 101,
            "advanced" : 100,
            "needTime" : 0,
            "needYield" : 0,
            "saveState" : 3,
            "restoreState" : 3,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "limitAmount" : 100,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "filter" : {
                    "$and" : [
                        {
                            "receivedTime" : {
                                "$lt" : ISODate("2021-05-31T03:00:00.000+03:00")
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "receivedTime" : {
                                "$gt" : ISODate("2020-12-31T02:00:00.000+02:00")
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "nReturned" : 100,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                "works" : 100,
                "advanced" : 100,
                "needTime" : 0,
                "needYield" : 0,
                "saveState" : 3,
                "restoreState" : 3,
                "isEOF" : 0,
                "docsExamined" : 100,
                "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "nReturned" : 100,
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                    "works" : 100,
                    "advanced" : 100,
                    "needTime" : 0,
                    "needYield" : 0,
                    "saveState" : 3,
                    "restoreState" : 3,
                    "isEOF" : 0,
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "meterid" : 1,
                        "receivedTime" : -1
                    },
                    "indexName" : "meterid_time_idx",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "multiKeyPaths" : {
                        "meterid" : [ ],
                        "receivedTime" : [ ]
                    },
                    "isUnique" : false,
                    "isSparse" : false,
                    "isPartial" : false,
                    "indexVersion" : 2,
                    "direction" : "forward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "meterid" : [
                            "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                        ],
                        "receivedTime" : [
                            "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                        ]
                    },
                    "keysExamined" : 100,
                    "seeks" : 1,
                    "dupsTested" : 0,
                    "dupsDropped" : 0,
                    "indexDef" : {
                        "indexName" : "meterid_time_idx",
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "multiKeyPaths" : {
                            "meterid" : [ ],
                            "receivedTime" : [ ]
                        },
                        "keyPattern" : {
                            "meterid" : 1,
                            "receivedTime" : -1
                        },
                        "isUnique" : false,
                        "isSparse" : false,
                        "isPartial" : false,
                        "direction" : "forward"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

However, if I reverse the sort order ({ meterid: -1 }), the query is very slow, and I can see that the same index is used, but the number of documents scanned is huge:

```
    "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "LIMIT",
            "limitAmount" : 100,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "filter" : {
                    "$and" : [
                        {
                            "receivedTime" : {
                                "$lt" : ISODate("2021-05-31T03:00:00.000+03:00")
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "receivedTime" : {
                                "$gt" : ISODate("2020-12-31T02:00:00.000+02:00")
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "meterid" : 1,
                        "receivedTime" : -1
                    },
                    "indexName" : "meterid_time_idx",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "multiKeyPaths" : {
                        "meterid" : [ ],
                        "receivedTime" : [ ]
                    },
                    "isUnique" : false,
                    "isSparse" : false,
                    "isPartial" : false,
                    "indexVersion" : 2,
                    "direction" : "backward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "meterid" : [
                            "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                        ],
                        "receivedTime" : [
                            "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
"executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 100,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 185544,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 10292501,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 10292501,
        "executionStages" : {
            "stage" : "LIMIT",
            "nReturned" : 100,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 19783,
            "works" : 10292502,
            "advanced" : 100,
            "needTime" : 10292401,
            "needYield" : 0,
            "saveState" : 229475,
            "restoreState" : 229475,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "limitAmount" : 100,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "filter" : {
                    "$and" : [
                        {
                            "receivedTime" : {
                                "$lt" : ISODate("2021-05-31T03:00:00.000+03:00")
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "receivedTime" : {
                                "$gt" : ISODate("2020-12-31T02:00:00.000+02:00")
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "nReturned" : 100,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 19698,
                "works" : 10292501,
                "advanced" : 100,
                "needTime" : 10292401,
                "needYield" : 0,
                "saveState" : 229475,
                "restoreState" : 229475,
                "isEOF" : 0,
                "docsExamined" : 10292501,
                "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "nReturned" : 10292501,
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 1945,
                    "works" : 10292501,
                    "advanced" : 10292501,
                    "needTime" : 0,
                    "needYield" : 0,
                    "saveState" : 229475,
                    "restoreState" : 229475,
                    "isEOF" : 0,
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "meterid" : 1,
                        "receivedTime" : -1
                    },
                    "indexName" : "meterid_time_idx",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "multiKeyPaths" : {
                        "meterid" : [ ],
                        "receivedTime" : [ ]
                    },
                    "isUnique" : false,
                    "isSparse" : false,
                    "isPartial" : false,
                    "indexVersion" : 2,
                    "direction" : "backward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "meterid" : [
                            "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                        ],
                        "receivedTime" : [
                            "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                        ]
                    },
                    "keysExamined" : 10292501,
                    "seeks" : 1,
                    "dupsTested" : 0,
                    "dupsDropped" : 0
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

even if I try to add an index such as this:

```
(meterid:-1 , receivedTime:-1)
```

I can see that it is not used. The previous index is still used.

So the questions are:

1. Why is Mongo behaving like this and
2. How can I achieve better performance for the descending sort too.

Comment: What is `meterid` exactly? is it randomly generated or monotonically increasing?

Comment: Actually is a given number of a meter, so you can say it is randomly genrated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there's no satisfying answer I can give, in "theory" Mongo can utilise the same index for both ascending and descending sorts as it can scan the index tree both ways meaning the "new" index is somewhat redundant.

What I suspect is happening is that you data isn't as "random" as you think and "larger" `meterid`'s have some underlined behaviours attached to them (less frequently used, deprecated, ... )

This means finding the 100 matching documents is harder, and mongo is forced to scan more documents to find them.

A good sanity check would be to fetch the "largest" `meterid`'s and see if my theory is correct, that they do not have ( or have very little ) data in that date range.

I would actually appreciate if you could provide an update in such case as I am interested in finding out more.

As to what you could do to improve this specific query is build a new index `(receivedTime:-1, meterid:-1)` or `(receivedTime:-1, meterid:1)`, this will ( under the assumption I'm right ) make the amount of data inspected for the query smaller, and would probably boost performance for the "slower" query, You can use [$hint](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/hint/) to force Mongo to use a specific index this will help corroborate any possible explanations.

Comment: I was thinking along the same lines with the last paragraph. Since `receivedTime` becomes the prefix index, mongodb will be able to optimise fetching documents within the given range for inspection. However, for the same reason, the `sort` operation on `meterid` will take longer to execute. But then again, since the sort operation works on a smaller data set, the overall performance could be faster.

Comment: Using a hint for the reverse index - (meterid:-1 , receivedTime:-1) - swithced performance to be fast for descending sort order ({ meterid: -1 }). I do not like to use hints, and perfer to count on the planner, so this planner bahviour still not quite understood.